# Intersection of circle and line.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Now we can realize that intersection  of two parallel lines at point of infinity in projective space. I can manage to visualize this and compute it. My issue is  if we have the two varieties 
$ X_1= Z (x^2+y^2-1) $ 
And 
$X_2=Z (x-5) $
Visualization of these is hard to see that they intersect, but according to Bezouts thrm, they have to intesect at two points. Any explanation here is appreciated.
Just to bring to your attention that I am looking for explanation how many points of intersection and their multiplicity, how to visualize them.

Comment: The points seem to be $5,\pm 2i$

Comment: In order to make Bezout's Theorem fully work, there are two major issues: the first is that, as you notice, intersections may escape to infinity. The solution is to compactify affine space and thus pass to projective space. The second issue is that you need the ground field to be *algebraically closed*. For example, you pass from considering real numbers to complex numbers. However, notice that with this operation the topological dimension doubles: a curve becomes a surface for example. When you draw your plane curves you are only considering a slice of them: their *real* points.